# How do I automatically remap touchpad buttons in RHEL 7?

Tags: rhel, touchpad

On RHEL 7.4, the Dell Latitude 7490's touchpad and mouse buttons default to touchpad clicks acting as left-clicks, left button clicks acting as right-clicks, and right button clicks acting as middle-clicks. I can use the following command to remap the buttons once I've logged in:

```
xinput set-button-map "Dell081C:00 044E:121F Touchpad" 2 3 1
```

However, this is fragile: if I modify touchpad settings using the GNOME Tweak Tool, the mapping gets messed up (becomes 1 3 3). Additionally the mapping is still messed up at the gdm login screen, preventing session selection (because touchpad clicking is disabled). How can I remap the buttons so they work properly at the gdm login screen and stay that way for any user session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit /etc/gdm/Init/Default and add the following line (before the exit line):

```
/usr/bin/xmodmap -e 'pointer = 2 3 1'
```

It looks like this problem is gone in RHEL 7.6 and the touchpad, trackpoint, and buttons work as expected.